# How to put 2 SQL querys together?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, input

I'm trying to put together 2 sql query one for name :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE '" .$name ."'ORDER BY id DESC";
```

and one to get $from and $to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE time BETWEEN ('$from') AND ('$to')";
```

Can you suggest how it is possible to combine these two query to show one name selected aswell and from and to for that name that is selected aswell as to just show all results for name selected without the from and to?

Comment: Please fix your tags, you probably don't use both `mysql` and `sql-server`

Comment: Can you provide some sample records and the expected output?  This will help us to help you.

Comment: Found answer : $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE '" .$name ."' and time between ifnull(timestamp('$from'),time) and ifnull(timestamp('$to'),time) ORDER BY id DESC";

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Union` to combine the results of both queries

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE '" .$name ."'
union all
SELECT * FROM register WHERE time BETWEEN ('$from') AND ('$to')
```

Comment: Answer updated .check once...Thanks @ Evaldas Buinauskas

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE time BETWEEN @from AND @to
UNION
SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE @name ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `UNION`, or alternatively, you could use `OR` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM register
WHERE name LIKE '" .$name ."'
    OR time BETWEEN ('$from') AND ('$to')
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: If I select just name I get results for just name which is good but if I put from and to for that name I get all names for the from and to selected?

Comment: @Jonas That's right. If that's not correct, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: Sorry I asked to show all results for name selected and not all names in database?

Comment: @Jonas Please rephrase that, or even better, add test data and expected output to your question as it's unclear what you need now.

Comment: @Jonas perhaps just replace `OR` with `AND` in my query?

Comment: Thanks but if I add AND I get no results if just name entered. but get results if I add from and to ?

Comment: Seems to only let me have one or the over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100355/discussion-between-jonas-and-evaldas-buinauskas).

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE '" .$name ."' and time between ifnull(timestamp('$from'),time) and ifnull(timestamp('$to'),time) ORDER BY id DESC";

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE '" .$name ."' 
          OR time BETWEEN ('$from') AND ('$to')
    ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is  unclear but still can try something like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE '" .$name ."'
OR (time BETWEEN ('$from') AND ('$to')) ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: Sorry what part of the question don't you understand? I want to select a name from database which will show all results for name, if I from and to that name as well to show results for that one name with the from and to?

Comment: You need `AND` not `OR` . Can you try above query ?

Comment: Thanks but if I add AND I get no results if just name entered. but get results if I add from and to ? and OR gives me name results and if I add from and to I get the results in the picture about.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was after, thanks to my Oracle programmer you know who you are, Thought I share:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE '" .$name ."' and time between ifnull(timestamp('$from'),time) and ifnull(timestamp('$to'),time) ORDER BY id DESC";
```